# less content unrecognized input

Tags: css, less, preprocessor

This is my less code and my preprocessor is telling me that **content: " ";** is unrecognized input. Help?

```
#top-nav{
    position: relative;
    height: @top-nav-height;
    line-height: @top-nav-height;
    background: #990000;
    z-index: 5;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    &:before {
        display: block; 
        content: " "; 
        position: absolute; 
        width: auto; 
        z-index: 0; 
        top: 0; 
        left: -100%; 
        bottom: 0; 
        right: -100%; 
        background-color: #990000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im also using LESS and dont have any problems using `content: " ";`. Can you be more specific? Like showing a image of the error itself?

Comment: Can you put your html?

Comment: I just tested it, and it doenst give any error with the latest version of less.js. I copied your snippet. Im guessing it has to do with the version you use. Which version do you use?

Comment: I bet you have some non-printing unicode character character there instead of a space. Do you even need a space though? Standard is `""` or `''`, and control the `width` or `padding` directly